# Mixed SRID Geometries

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm developing a PostGIS function to return a value when longitude and latitude are passed as variables to the function.

```
CREATE  FUNCTION flood_location(long float, lat float) RETURNS varchar(40) AS $BODY$
        BEGIN
                RETURN l.committee_new
                from land_ownership.council_owned_land l
                (long,lat),4236),l.wkb_geometry);
                where ST_WITHIN(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lat,long),4236),l.wkb_geometry);
        END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However the function is currently returning the following error when I trying to call the function.

```
select flood_location(-2.142,53.41862);

ERROR:  contains: Operation on mixed SRID geometries (MultiPolygon, 4326) != (Point, 4236)
    CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT l.committee_new
                    from land_ownership.council_owned_land l
                    (lat,long),4236),l.wkb_geometry);
                    where ST_WITHIN(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long,lat),4236),l.wkb_geometry)"
    PL/pgSQL function flood_location(double precision,double precision) line 3 at RETURN
    SQL state: XX000
```

The SRID of the land_ownership table is 4236?

Comment: EPSG:4236 is `GEODCRS["Hu Tzu Shan 1950"`. Do you mean it in your function? Long-lat is correct order for ST_MakePoint.

Comment: Hi sorry I was trying a few things and posted the wrong code! but well spotted! I have posted the correct answer below, needed to use the ST_Transform function. Thank you.

Comment: Confirm that you really work with Taiwanese coordinate system  http://epsg.io/4236 and not with global WGS84 http://epsg.io/4326.

Comment: the line ` (long,lat),4236),l.wkb_geometry);` makes no sense (between the `from` and the `where`. It is an incomplete line and the SQL simply can't run with it

Comment: Turns out you are correct, I'm using the incorrect ESPG! Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are checking a coordinate from the UK, and the polygon CRS is either WGS84 with a typo, or a CRS for [Taiwan](https://epsg.io/4236) with a way out of bounds coordinate.

Since the typo is more likely, you need to fix the query

```
where ST_WITHIN(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long,lat),4326),l.wkb_geometry)
```

Else if you are really using 4236 (Taiwan), you would need to fix the data and the column

```sql
ALTER TABLE land_ownership 
   ALTER COLUMN wkb_geometry 
     TYPE geometry(Point, 4236) 
     USING st_SetSrid(wkb_geometry,4236);
```

You may use `USING st_transform(wkb_geometry,4236);` instead if you are sure that the actual polygon data is truly in 4326.